# How do i start up Snort software?

Tags: snort

I am very new to snort. I have downloaded Snort onto Windows 7 and i want to run it? I opened up the snort.exe file in the Snort installed folder in my computer folder of windows 7. I ran it as a command prompt?Is that correct?

Comment: What happened? How did it not work as you expected?

Comment: I don't know? I opened Snort.exe file form the Snort installed folder in my computer folder of windows 7. Its my first time using snort. It ran as command prompt with recurring messages containing some captured packet appearing. Is there a GUI for the snort software?

Answer (score 1):

Snort is typically run from the CLI (as simple as typing 'snort' in cmd) and when it starts successfully, you should see messages about the version, (running) mode, rules engine and pre-processors.

Here's a link to installing and running Snort on Windows 7 - http://www.snort.org/assets/151/Installing_Snort_2.8.6.1_on_Windows_7.pdf.

Snort is designed to run on Linux though and I don't believe they put anywhere as much time into developing for Windows platforms.